# PostgreSQL is not deleting rows from a WITH ... AS UPDATE clause

Tags: postgresql

I would like to write a query that performs an UPDATE, and if the resulting row matches a constraint, performs a DELETE.

To test, I have the following table:

```sql
# CREATE TABLE counts (id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, count BIGINT NOT NULL);
# INSERT INTO counts (count) VALUES (5), (1);
# SELECT * FROM counts;
 id | count 
----+-------
  1 |     5
  2 |     1
(2 rows)
```

Now, I wrote the following query to subtract one `count` from the `counts` table for a particular `id`, deleting the row if the `count` becomes 0:

```sql
WITH updated_counts AS (
  UPDATE counts
  SET count=count - 1
  WHERE id=2
  RETURNING *
)
DELETE FROM counts
USING updated_counts
WHERE counts.id=updated_counts.id
  AND updated_counts.count=0;
```

Running this (in a transaction) does change the `counts` table, but does not delete the row (the returned tag is `DELETE 0`).

```sql
# SELECT * FROM counts;
 id | count 
----+-------
  1 |     5
  2 |     0
(2 rows)
```

Rolling back this transaction and retrying with a query that shows the result of the WITH clause, I do see the row to be deleted with the correct count:

```sql
# WITH updated_counts AS (UPDATE counts 
                             SET count=count - 1
                           WHERE id=2
                       RETURNING *
                         )
SELECT *
  FROM updated_counts;

 id | count 
----+-------
  2 |     0
(1 row)
```

The following query also does not have the intended result:

```sql
# WITH updated_counts AS (UPDATE counts
                             SET count=count - 1
                           WHERE id=2
                       RETURNING *)
DELETE
  FROM counts
 WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                FROM updated_counts
               WHERE count=0
             );
DELETE 0
# SELECT * FROM counts;
 id | count 
----+-------
  1 |     5
  2 |     0
(2 rows)
```

Could someone explain why, even though the `updated_counts` contains the right row, the `DELETE` is not deleting it? And, ideally, how to fix the query so that it does?

This is on Postgres server version 15.1, client version 14.7.

Comment: [Read the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) from *Trying to update the same row twice in a single statement is not supported (...)*

Comment: Also look at this recent thread on pgsql-general, [Data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAMX8OqKTEVZSyi2ZXD9Z_ZV717FwDwx4-OB%3D4xH1Q9Z885VmDg%40mail.gmail.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** update the same row twice in a single statement. You can break into 2 statements or reverse the order of the operation. Postgres does not throw an error when you try to update a non-existing row. Since subtracting 1 from a column value then deleting if the result is 0 is the same thing as deleting where the initial value is 1 you can reverse the `update` and `delete` doing the delete first. So:

```
with delete_1_counts as (
  delete from counts 
    where count = 1
      and id=2 
  returning id
)
update counts
   set count = count - 1
  from delete_1_counts  
where counts.id=delete_1_counts.id;
```